# alias .="cd .." causing bash to start at root

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, command-line-interface

If I add the alias `alias .="cd .."` to my .bash_aliases file (sourced from .bashrc) it causes every new shell I make to start at `/`. I am guessing this is just a fundamental thing I don't understand.

Any ideas?

Comment: What prompted you to create such a wonderful alias?

Comment: I have a bunch after these, it is super handy. You just type one dot to go up one level, two for two dirs up and so on. Makes like nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` refers to the current directory, while `..` refers to the one upper in the dirs hierarchy.

What must be happening is that in your `bashrc` you have some `.` after this alias definition, so it gets called and hence you are moved to the parent directory.

So:

- you enter and you are in `/home/your_home`
- you set `alias .="cd .."`.
- some dot `.` is found while reading `.bashrc`.
- this dot is executed as to be an alias, so you get `cd ..`, which moves you to `/home`.
- you probable have more than one `.` and it must get executed again, moving you from `/home` to `/`.

Solution:

- Create an alias with a better name that does not have any predefined meaning.
- Move your alias sourcing to the bottom of .bashrc.

Comment: Yes, I do have more after `alias .="cd .."` `alias ..="cd ../.."` and so on to about 8 levels or so.

Comment: Perfect, great explanation! I did find the . after the .bash_aliases sourcing in .bashrc. I just moved my .bash_aliases source to the very end of .bashrc and everything works great now!

Comment: Yeah, according to Gorden's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17728783/292408) `.` is a build in shell command and will break other things. I am going to prefix all my alias commands with u, so it will just be u., u.., u..., etc to go up levels. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it is safer this way! As a side note, It happened to me some time ago to use `alias test="cd ..."` and then got some strange behaviours, as `test` is the conditional command.

Answer (score 2):

`.` is a builtin shell command, equivalent to "source" -- it executes a shell script in the current shell, thus allowing it to define variables, functions, etc.

This `.` command is used fairly often in scripts to bring in definitions from other scripts. When you alias `.` to something else, you override the standard definition and **break every script that uses it**.

Please do not redefine standard commands.

(P.S. it's actually more complicated than that, because aliases are only active in interactive shells, so `.` would do completely different things in interactive vs. non-interactive shells. This doesn't really help the situation.)

Comment: Ahh! That helps greatly, I was wondering why that was some of the commands. Guess I cannot use the . trick. Maybe I will prefix all my up level aliases with u (for up) and that will make it bulletproof! Thanks!